# Why$ f(x-x_0) \star g(x) = (f \star g)(x-x_0)$?

Tags: convolution

Convolution between 2 functions $f$ and $g$ is defined as $$(f\star g)(x) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x') g(x-x') dx'.$$

Shift invariance of convolution is said to be the property that $$f(x-x_0) \star g(x) = (f \star g)(x-x_0).$$

Firstly, what does $f(x-x_0) \star g(x)$ represent and why $ f(x-x_0) \star g(x) = (f \star g)(x-x_0)$?

Comment: I assume your functions are $2\pi$ periodic, aren't they?

Comment: $f(x - x_0)$ represents the function $x\mapsto f(x-x_0)$.

Comment: @eranreches i have no information on that. Does it only hold when it is $2\pi$ periodic?

Comment: generally yes. See the answer by @Abishanka Saha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(f\star g)(x-x_0) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x') g(x-x_0-x') dx'.$$
Aplly the transformation of variables $y=x'+x_0$, then $dy=dx'$ and the integral becomes
$$\int_{-\pi+x_0}^{\pi+x_0} f(y-x_0) g(x-y) dy$$
But $$f(x-x_0) \star g(x)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(y-x_0) g(x-y) dy$$
Then if $f$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ then $f(x-x_0) \star g(x) = (f \star g)(x-x_0)$

Comment: How do you get your "but" statement?

Comment: This is how the convolution is defined. $g$ convoluted with shifted $f$. Think of $f(x-x_0)$ as a function $h(x)$ taking the value $f(a-x_0)$ at $x=a$

Comment: I am still confused. Should $f(x-x_0) \star g(x) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x-x_0)g(x-x') dx'$ then?

Comment: $f(x-x_0) \star g(x) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} h(x')g(x-x') dx'=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x'-x_0)g(x-x') dx'$

Comment: yup which does not match what follows in "but". I meant shouldn't ... then? in my previous comment.

Comment: It follows exactly. Only the variable here is named $x'$ instead of $y$ used in the solution

Comment: The problem is $y = x' + x_0$ as you define earlier so $y \neq x'$? How is that equal then?

Comment: It doesnt matter what the varibale of integration is. If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an integrable function then $\int f(y)dy$ and $\int f(x)dx$ bears the same meaning